# How to get current seed in R

Tags: r, random

I am running a function with random factor in R, and I realized that I forgot to run `set.seed()` before running this function.

Is there a way I can retrieve the `seed` value R is using (I suppose it will be an arbitrary number, but doesn't matter) so I can reproduce the execution?

Comment: No. You cannot get a previous random state from the current random state. You'll need to rerun the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current random state using `.Random.seed`. However, you'd need the previous state for reproducing your results and it's not possible to get that.

(Well, the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) is not cryptographically secure, so maybe it could be possible, but certainly not practical.)