# Get a seed to generate a specific set of pseudo-casual number

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I was wondering if there is a way in R to find the specific seed that generates a specific set of numbers;

For example:

```
sample(1:300, 10)
```

I want to find the seed that gives me, as the output of the previous code:

```
58 235 243  42 281 137   2 219 284 184
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current seed in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690102/how-to-get-current-seed-in-r)

Comment: I strongly believe this is next to impossible.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no elegant way to do this, but you could brute force it:

```r
desired_output <- c(58, 235, 243, 42, 281, 137, 2, 219, 284, 184)
MAX_SEED <- .Machine$integer.max
MIN_SEED <- MAX_SEED * -1
i  <- MIN_SEED
while (i < MAX_SEED - 1) {
    set.seed(i)
    actual_output <- sample(1:300, 10)
    if (identical(actual_output, desired_output)) {
        message("Seed found! Seed is: ", i)
        break
    }
    i  <- i + 1
}
```

This takes 11.5 seconds to run with the first `1e6` seeds on my laptop - so if you're unlucky then it would take about 7 hours to run. Also, this is exactly the kind of task you could run in parallel in separate threads to cut the time down quite a bit.

EDIT: Updated to include negative seeds which I had not considered. So in fact it could take twice as long.

Comment: You should also include the negative seeds if you are looking for a bruteforce approach. This answer also assumes that there _exists_ a seed that will provide the desired output.

Comment: Great point - didn't think about negative seeds. I have updated the answer. Re the assumption - yes I have assumed that this is the output of some code run elsewhere that the OP wants to reproduce.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to run this code? I would assume that `MIN_SEED:MAX_SEED-1` would not fit into memory.

Comment: Instead of creating a ginormous vector, iterate through i <- i + 1, use set.seed(-i) and set.seed(i) and use while loop instead of forloop. This should make a bit quicker(?).

Comment: @zx8754 yes that's much better - have updated. I want to write a parallel version of it with `futures` at some point and try it on my HPC - if I get around to it then I will update further.