# Can you retrospectively find the seed that R used to get a sample?

Tags: r, statistics, sampling

I didn't realize you'd have to set.seed() every time before you draw a sample, so I only set it at the top of a chunk where two samples will be drawn. Now I realized my second sample is different every time I run the code. Luckily I have a list of the unique IDs of each of the 120 items in that sample. Is there a way for me to somehow get a "seed" that would generate this exact sample again? The problem is that I have overwritten documents containing info from this sample due to running chunks that follow the sample command, before realizing it would be different every time.

Comment: Not easily - you can brute force it if you know the output that the random seed created, which it sounds like you do. I answered another question once that asked the same thing with some code which set out how to do this - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756367/get-a-seed-to-generate-a-specific-set-of-pseudo-casual-number).