# How to get the actual seed which we set using set.seed() in R?

Tags: r

I want to get the seed back which I set using `set.seed()`. Say if I set seed as `set.seed(123)`, I want to get 123 back if I called some sort of function like `get_seed()`.

I want to make sure that if the seed is set properly. Also, I want to see what's the value of seed when I set using `Sys.time()`.

Comment: See: [Can I get.seed() somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19614314/10488504)

Comment: Try `.Random.seed`. It's documented in `help("Random")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function that is able to return the seed number that has been set at an earlier point in time.

The only way is to store the number somewhere before calling `set.seed()`. If you haven't done that, then there is no way to know which seed has been set.

Comment: If you have the output from immediately after you set the seed then [it can be brute forced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756367/get-a-seed-to-generate-a-specific-set-of-pseudo-casual-number) - it won't be quick but if you're unlucky we're talking at most days rather than years.

Comment: @SamR: I have not thought about bruteforcing it, nice idea! However, it will only work if you have the output, and if `set.seed()` has been called directly before the function that generated the output. Further, this might work with small vectors, but if it is a computation-heavy operation, it might take much longer.

Comment: Yes absolutely - a last resort that might work in a desperate situation, depending on the circumstances. Definitely not a recommended workflow!